# Increment top position absolute on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have two elements, one positioned on the left and one on the right in absolute. I would like the right element, When it will disappear ((Exit the window), that it remains fixed (**without using position: fixed**).

I would like the value "top" to update but I can not do it and I can not find anything on the internet.

```css
div.container{
  position: relative;
}

article{
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

aside{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et dolor elementum, mollis ipsum eget, fermentum odio. Nunc pretium, dui ut posuere tristique, lacus lacus vestibulum dui, eu finibus dui mi quis felis. Sed nibh odio, ultrices vel dui eget, eleifend efficitur leo. Suspendisse dui metus, maximus quis lacus in, condimentum viverra mauris. Nunc finibus dui felis, sed egestas purus posuere et. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque luctus, erat vitae fermentum sodales, nisi diam congue augue, nec ultrices magna eros non mi. Nam semper sollicitudin quam, sit amet porta purus tristique vitae. Suspendisse suscipit, ipsum vel mattis pretium, urna erat imperdiet metus, at dictum est metus quis nisl. Duis rhoncus leo sed erat pulvinar, sit amet auctor est placerat. Duis tincidunt velit dolor, quis luctus felis venenatis quis. Sed odio urna, malesuada in mauris sit amet, lobortis hendrerit turpis. In fringilla metus diam, ut malesuada augue elementum ut. Donec id pharetra elit. Maecenas maximus vitae magna nec gravida. Morbi ac pellentesque mi.

Sed tristique fermentum metus in finibus. Sed commodo ultricies justo eu gravida. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum mattis tortor sem, quis egestas augue tempus at. Curabitur molestie ut dui ac pretium. Donec vehicula enim ut quam ullamcorper sollicitudin. Donec pretium tristique sapien, id maximus nulla fermentum nec. Sed aliquet consectetur nisi, ut finibus erat vestibulum sit amet. Ut suscipit condimentum nisi.

Aenean eleifend tempus aliquam. Maecenas a fringilla arcu. Nunc leo mi, venenatis sit amet libero luctus, vulputate luctus erat. Fusce ex felis, auctor consequat imperdiet quis, finibus vel est. Morbi vitae pretium felis, id vulputate justo. Phasellus nunc enim, vestibulum ac velit in, finibus tincidunt diam. Cras posuere in metus quis volutpat. Cras posuere metus vitae turpis placerat laoreet. Quisque dignissim quam ut nisl euismod viverra. Aenean sed augue sed lectus congue accumsan. Quisque vel pellentesque enim, ut tincidunt tortor. Vestibulum vel ex nec velit facilisis posuere eget a elit. Phasellus non vulputate turpis, vel venenatis odio.
</p>
  </article>
  
  <aside>
    My Aside
  </aside>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jimmylet/puxf496d/)

Thank you very much !

Comment: What do you want to update `top` to?

Comment: Your article top is already set to the top of your aside. They are directly inline.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? I don't think anyone really understands what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

use `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`

```
aside{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/puxf496d/1/

Comment: Precisely no, I can not use the fixed position.

Comment: @Jeremy whats the reasoning behind not being able to use fixed positioning?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You want your aside to stand in place when scrolling, right? I don't know why you want to do it like that, but you can use Javascript to increment the top property of your aside.

An example using JQuery.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){        
    var top = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.container aside').css('top',top);
});
```